# Elm: How to transform Html FooMsg to Html Msg

Tags: elm

I'm new to Elm. I have a site with two pages: Home and Signup.

Home has it's own view and Signup has it's own view, but they both return `Html Msg`. I'd like to change it so that Home returns `Html HomeMsg` and Signup returns `Html SignupMsg`.

Writing these view functions is easy of course, but I think my top-level view function needs to transform the result into `Html Msg`.

Here is the Msg type.

```
type Msg 
  = Home HomeMsg
  | Signup SignupMsg
  | OnLocationChange Location
```

I think I need some sort of `map` function to do this like

```
view : Model -> Html Msg 
view model =
    case model.route of
        Model.HomeRoute ->
            map Home (homeView model)

        Model.SignupRoute ->
            map Signup (signupView model)

        Model.NotFoundRoute ->
            notFoundView
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a `map` function.  It belongs to `Html` module.

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#map

Your code becomes:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg 
view model =
    case model.route of
        Model.HomeRoute ->
            Html.map Home (homeView model)

        Model.SignupRoute ->
            Html.map Signup (signupView model)

        Model.NotFoundRoute ->
            notFoundView
```